# Line to the right margin of pace with css

Tags: css

I would like to have h1 headers be followed by a thick line that goes to the right margin of the page.

Kind of like this:

[image]

except that I would like all the black lines to end at the same point on the right - independently of the length of the h1 content.

I got this far with this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #9E7046
}

body * {
  font-family: 'Helvetica'
}

h1 {
  font-size: 200pt;
  color: #E8E8E8;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  margin-left: 1em
}

h1:after {
  background-color: #262626;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 50%;
  top: -52px
}

h1:after {
  left: 0.2em;
  margin-right: -50%;
  width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Short</h1>
<h1>Longer</h1>
<h1>Very<br/>long</h1>
```

but I can't figure how to get the lines to have variable length and end at the same point on the x axis.

How can I do that with CSS (no javascript)?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [horizontal flex layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox) for each `<h1>`. You can then use `flex-grow` to grow out the line into the remaining empty space left by the text.

```css
body {
  background-color: #9E7046
}

body * {
  font-family: 'Helvetica'
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 200pt;
  color: #E8E8E8;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  margin-left: 1em
}

h1:after {
  background-color: #262626;
  content: "";
  height: 36px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Short</h1>
<h1>Longer</h1>
<h1>Very<br/>long</h1>
```